# Android application label textView Style

Tags: android, textview, label

Is there any way that I can use the same `textView` style which is applied on the application label which shows on the Home Screen?

Comment: Not really, insofar as there are hundreds of home screen implementations, any of which can do whatever they want in terms of how they render text.

Comment: Ok so when we put android:label="APP NAME" they all looks same on one particular home screen they must have some style for them. Or it is launcher level implementation?

Comment: "Or it is launcher level implementation?" -- yes. There are hundreds of home screen implementations, representing hundreds of launchers. There is no requirement for any home screen to *have* a launcher, let alone show a text caption for icons, let alone use some specific text style for that caption.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.. @CommonsWare